# Omega template.php form alter

Tags: forms, theming

I'm trying to edit default user login block.

I successfully changed it by creating custom `block--user--login.tpl.php` inside `omega-starter/templates`, but I don't want to write whole block code. I only want to change certain fields.

I tried to use this code in `template.php` :

```
function omega_starter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'user-login-form') {
    //dpm($form);
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t("Custom login button!");
  }
}
```

It doesn't make any changes. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: this issue is reported [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7). maybe it is because your default theme is different from the theme you are editting.

Comment: As default theme you mean Drupal default themes such as "Bartik"?

Comment: you have implemented your code in template.php file which is in your theme folder , so it is called only when you are using that theme . I usually prefer to change forms using modules

Comment: Which module do I need to edit if I want to change user login form? Do I need to create custom module, because I don't see such?

Comment: Create a custom module and use hook_form_alter there

Comment: and 1 more question:) you are using drupal 7?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I checked your code again and found the answer , change your code to this :

```
function omega_starter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form['#id'] == 'user_login_form') { //form ID was changed
    //dpm($form);
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = t("Custom login button!");
  }
}
```

Comment: [Node Buttons Edit](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_buttons_edit) Module also can be used , for this situation.

Comment: Doesn't work, caches cleared. Is there a way to change those strings without modules, by editing code directly? I'm afraid that those little modules will be used once and left as trash.

Comment: Does dpm function works? I want to check if it goes to if statement.add dsm('hook is working') before if statement to see if hook is fired or not.

Comment: But earlier id `user-login-form` is correct, i checked html output.

Comment: I get `Fatal error: Call to undefined function dpm()` .

Comment: Sorry I forget , you have to install and enable [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Module , I know maybe you don't like installing modules but try this one , it is one of the must have ones

Comment: Nope, I like installing modules, it's a pleasure with drush :) 
Now I get no error, but also no output from dpm.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26721/discussion-between-alireza-tabatabaeian-and-neone).

Answer (score 0):

Just for other people dealing with such problem , we tried hard and finally the problem was found , there was a conflict between `block--user--login.tpl.php` and `template.php` . actually `block--user--login.tpl.php` was overriding the output .
so one possible reasons in such situation is another function is conflicting the exiting . now how to understad? Theme Developer module could be one solution , this module tells you which functions are building an output , if you want to use it , its 7.x.1.12 version works fine (but still some problems) . check to see "[How to find which templates are affecting a display?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/168261/how-to-find-which-templates-are-affecting-a-display)"